# Questions related to android:onClick="selfDestruct" xml method

Tags: android, button, listener

New to android and programming in general. This question might sound silly but I'd appreciate the answer. The question description and reasoning is at the beginning and the question is at the end of it all.

I want to apply a listener to a button in android. The way I understood from android.googlesource.com is that there is two way to do it:

1. applying an `OnClickListener` to the button in the `activity.java`
   or
2. assign a method to my button in the `xml` layout using this

{`@link android.R.attr#onClick android:onClick`}

they gave the following xml layout example:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="selfDestruct"
    android:text="@string/self_destruct" />
```

plus the the code in `activity.java`

```
 public void selfDestruct(View view) {
    // Kabloey
}
```

[android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Button.java)

Questions:

1. According to this: {`@link android.R.attr#onClick android:onClick`} `android.R.attr` in the example are the following:

   `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

   `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

   `android:text="@string/self_destruct"`

?

2. Does this:

   `android:text="@string/self_destruct"`

   `android:onClick="selfDestruct"`

mean that the button called self_destruct registered as a listener?

3. If I want to add more than one button listener in xml form how do I write it in the java document?

Thank you in advance
Really appreciate it.

Comment: You can't add more than one click listener

Answer (score 0):

> Does this:
>
> android:text="@string/self_destruct" android:onClick="selfDestruct"
>
> mean that the button called self_destruct registered as a listener?

The button isn't "called" anything, it just has the text of the value for `@string/self_destruct` defined in the `strings.xml` file.

But, yes, the `public void selfDestruct(View view)` method is the method that will be called for the listener that is setup by the XML.

> If I want to add more than one button listener in xml form how do I write it in the java document?

You can only set one click listener for a View.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, `layout_height`, `layout_width` and `text` are attributes. You
   can learn more about android attributes
   [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/R.attr.html).
   But keep in mind, that different views can use the same attributes
   in different way.
2. It does not. The `android:text` attribute in this sample just refer to a string-resource called `self_destruct` to decide which text should be shown within the button. To distinguish views you can use `android:id`.
3. As already mentioned by other people, you are able to specify only one `onClickListener` using XML.

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast Aleksandr. I have another question regarding the onClickListener. In my app that I would like to design I have several buttons. If I add an onClickListener using XML to each button will that work? Thank you again.